# Does reading directly from the Project Server database void the warranty?

Tags: database, project-server, support

I know that in SharePoint, it's hugely frowned upon to access content databases directly, and in fact Microsoft will stop giving you support if they find out you've touched the databases.

Is the same true for Project Server?  I've found some things online for Project Server 2007 and 2010 that talk about what the databases are that are used by Project Server, and how to access them, and there seems to be no cautionary warning or anything, so it seems as though it's a perfectly accepted practice.

I've also found some things that talk about how the multiple databases from the older versions of Project Server have now been merged into one database for Project Server 2016.  But those articles really didn't mention anything about getting in to that database to read it.

So for Project Server 2016 on-prem, how bad is it to read from the databases directly? No writing - read only - and I'm only talking about the database that holds the actual project data (tasks, baselines, etc.), not any content database for a related SharePoint site.  Would Microsoft stop giving us support if we do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Certain tables* are supported for reading directly from the database in Project Server only (this extends to the Content Database where Project Server data resides in 2016/2019), namely the database that were previously present in the Project Server 2013 Reporting database.

See the section titled Project Server database in [Project Server architecture](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/project/project-server-2013-architecture#general-architecture).